# is it safe to store stripe payment public key in firebase hosting script

Tags: javascript, firebase, stripe-payments, firebase-hosting

is it safe to store stripe payment public key in firebase hosting script/code (public key is actually uploaded into Github). is there any better way to save a public key?

Answer (score 2):

Yep! Public keys are public and meant to be shared. As long as you aren't exposing your private keys you will be all set.

From Stripe's documentation: "Publishable API keys are meant solely to identify your account with Stripe, they aren’t secret. In other words, they can safely be published in places like your Stripe.js JavaScript code, or in an Android or iPhone app." Read more about it [here](https://stripe.com/docs/keys).